# mysql join multiple table if there is any registration

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables, each with only 2 rows. T1 (id, name), T2(id,email), T3(id,phone). T1 has registrations at both id1 and id2, T2 has registration only on id1, on id2 is no registration (null) at email. T3 has regitrations on both id1 and id2.
I want to join T1, T2 and T3 with some conditions (name like '% etc %'). The result should be a table with (name, email, phone), but if the registration in one of the joined tables is NULL (ex T2 id2(email) is NULL), I want the result to be a table with only (name, phone)(T1+T3 because T2 has a null registration at id2)...some kind on multiple inner joins if column has a registration not NULL.
Thank you.

Comment: Please show what have you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to look into using `LEFT JOINs`:

```
SELECT T1.Name, T2.Email, T3.Phone 
FROM T1
    LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.id=T2.id
    LEFT JOIN T3 ON T1.id=T3.id
```

This will return all your records from Table T1, and only those matching from T2 and T3. The other fields will be NULL.

If however you want only those that match the criteria, then use INNER JOINs instead:

```
SELECT T1.Name, T2.Email, T3.Phone 
FROM T1
    INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.id=T2.id
    INNER JOIN T3 ON T1.id=T3.id
```

This will only return the matching records.

The comment you made about only returning 2 columns if one record is NULL -- I don't think that's the approach you want to take.  Return all your columns and handle this on your presentation side of things.  If you truly want dynamic columns, then you'll need to look into using Dynamic SQL.

--EDIT--

Dynamic SQL Approach:

```
SET @id = 2;
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT
    CONCAT(
      CASE WHEN EMail IS NOT NULL THEN 'Email' ELSE '' END,
      CASE WHEN EMail IS NOT NULL AND Phone IS NOT NULL THEN ',' ELSE '' END,
      CASE WHEN Phone IS NOT NULL THEN 'Phone' ELSE '' END)
    INTO @sql
FROM T1
    LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.id=T2.id
    LEFT JOIN T3 ON T1.id=T3.id
WHERE T1.Id = @id;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT Name, ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM T1
                      LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.id=T2.id
                      LEFT JOIN T3 ON T1.id=T3.id
                  WHERE T1.Id = ',@id);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0187e/12)

Comment: *...but if the registration in one of the joined tables is NULL (ex T2 id2(email) is NULL), I want the result to be a table with only (name, phone)(T1+T3 because T2 has a null registration at id2)...* -- how can this return two columns for instance?

Comment: @MachoPaay -- good point, wasn't quite sure what OP was asking.  I'll post an edit about returning different columns.

Comment: anyway your answer seems fine as you cannot dynamically return unequal column per execution unless the OP was to create dynamic sql.

Comment: the query returns ALWAYS JUST one row as result (=T1 (if not null)+ T2 (if not null)+T3(if not null)) E.G. T1 + T3 ad id 2 and T1 + T2 + T3 for id1...so there can be also 2 columns as result (if the third is null).

Comment: @user2127072 -- I'm still confused by your question.  Can you review this Fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0187e/1) and let me know your desired results?

Comment: for the query no 1 the result is name1, email1, and phone1 (3 columns cause none is null) and for query no 2 the result is name2 and phone2 cause email2 is null ().

Comment: @user2127072 -- a single SQL statement must return the same number of columns.  if you want different columns to be returned depending on the results, you'll have to look into dynamic sql (not recommending this at all).

Comment: As I said, the result is ALWAYS a table with JUST ONE row (one finding - the db and tables are made such a way). There will never be a table with first row with 3 columns and the second row with only 2 columns. Thanks

Comment: @sgeddes CREATE TABLE T1 (Id int, Name varchar(100));
CREATE TABLE T2 (Id int, Email varchar(100));
CREATE TABLE T3 (Id int, Phone varchar(100));

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (1,'Name1'),(2,'Name2');
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (1,'Email1');
INSERT INTO T3 VALUES (1,'Phone1'),(2,'Phone2');

Comment: So is a presentation side issue? (eg php...)?

Comment: @wwwglro -- like the new nick!  I still say handle this on the presentation side of things, but I edited my answer to show you how to use dynamic SQL to achieve via DB.

Comment: @sgeddes ...works great your last 'edit'. I simulated with 4 table and it works nice. So if I have multiple table, do I always have to test adiacent columns if they are NULL or not...? Thank you.